# How can I initialize an object of type interface with a constructor from a class that implements the parent interface?

Tags: java, interface

I have interface Worker, interface Painter that extends Worker and Person that implements Worker.
How do I create a Person that is also a Painter?

Do I have to create a subclass from Person?

Why does

```
Painter painter = new Person();
```

not work?

Comment: Either you have to create subclass of Person that implements Painter, or make the Person class implements Painter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Person` probably does not have the same methods as `Painter` and even if it did, the compiler doesn't know that.

Since you're variable is declared as a `Painter` though, you would be able to call methods from the `Painter` class. Instead of a `Painter`, `painter` contains a `Person` however.

So if you were to call a method that only `Painter` has, the method wouldn't be found, because, again, the variable `painter` actually contains a `Person` that doesn't necessarily have the same methods.

To solve this, make `Person` extend `Painter`, but I would recommend rethinking your logic and what you actually want to do.

Comment: I don't think making person extend painter makes sense since not all people are painters.
Is there a way to make an anonymous inner type that implements painter and is a person? 
I could also create a subclass of Person that implements Painter. But then I would have to do it for all types of workers.
If not what other logic do you suggest?

Comment: You could create a (possibly abstract) class that implements both `Worker` and `Person`, but as I said, rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also, if we're getting into logic related stuff, why does `Person` extend `Worker` and not the other way around? After all, not every person is a worker.

Comment: Person is a class and Worker is an interface. Person implements Worker. In my example being unemployed or retired is a type of worker. I guess occupation might be better term. 
Maybe I should have a different relation between the Person and worker.

Comment: Well, you're going to have to figure that logic stuff out for yourself. All I can help you with is provided in the answer.

Comment: Would composition make more sense here? Have an attribute in person that tells what's his occupation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212725/discussion-between-schred-and-antonio-craveiro).